# Input multiple time range then return all another time range

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm finding a solution that when I input a time range (or many time ranges) as an array, then it will return all another time ranges except the time range that I inputted.

**For example:** 

I input `[ 0 => ['start' => '8:30:00', 'end' => '9:00:00'], 1 => ['start' => '11:30:00', 'end' => '12:30:00']]`

(8:30:00 - 9:00:00), (11:30:00 - 12:30:00)

And all the time I want to receive from `8:00:00` to `17:00:00`

**The expected output that I want it returns is:**

`[ 0 => ['start' => '8:00:00', 'end' => '8:30:00'], 1 => ['start' => '09:00:00', 'end' => '11:30:00'], 2 => ['start' => '12:30:00', 'end' => '17:00:00']]`

(8:00:00 - 8:30:00), (09:00:00 - 11:30:00), (12:30:00 - 17:00:00)

Thank you.

Comment: What are these `time ranges`. Please provide your code.

Comment: It likes the ```booking time```, the time that I inputted is the ```booked time range```, and the ```time range``` I want to receive is ```avaiable booking time ranges```. I have't code it yet, because I'm finding solution for it.

Comment: Not an infrequent question try searching for mysql find available time slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use this concept. You dont need to use any datetime library or any other concept. Just paly with for loop will work fine.

```
<?php
$startingTime = '8:00:00';
$endingTime = '1:00:00';
$time = [ ['start' => '8:30:00', 'end' => '9:00:00'],
             ['start' => '11:30:00', 'end' => '12:30:00']];
$output = [];
for ($x = 0; $x <= count($time); $x++) {
    $t = $time[$x];
    $interval = [];
    $interval['start'] = $startingTime;
    $interval['end'] = ($t['start']=== NULL? $endingTime: $t['start'] );
    array_push($output,$interval);
    $startingTime = $t['end'];
}

print_r($output);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$aInputDate = [['start' => '08:30:00', 'end' => '09:00:00'],
               ['start' => '11:30:00', 'end' => '12:30:00']];

$sStartTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 08:00:00'));
$sEndTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 17:00:00'));

while ($sStartTime <= $sEndTime) {
    $aAllTime[] = date('H:i:s', $sStartTime);
    $sStartTime = strtotime('+30 minutes', $sStartTime);
}

foreach ($aInputDate as $key => $value) {
    $iStartKey = array_search($value['start'], $aAllTime);
    unset($aAllTime[$iStartKey]);
    $iStartKey = array_search($value['end'], $aAllTime);
    unset($aAllTime[$iStartKey]);
}

var_dump($aAllTime);
```